# Magento 2.3 API for get child category of specific category

Tags: magento2.3, category, api

I have tried with API:
`/rest/V1/categories/3` get that give the only id of child category not name etc.

get response like : `[children] => 4,5`

not come: children_data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found api belowed:

```
http://www.domain.com/rest/V1/categories?rootCategoryId=3
```

With this you can give any parent category id to parameter : `rootCategoryId`

And can get response like:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 3
    [parent_id] => 2
    [name] => 
    [is_active] => 
    [position] => 1
    [level] => 2
    [product_count] => 
    [children_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [parent_id] => 3
                    [name] => 
                    [is_active] => 
                    [position] => 1
                    [level] => 3
                    [product_count] => 
                    [children_data] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [parent_id] => 3
                    [name] => 
                    [is_active] => 
                    [position] => 2
                    [level] => 3
                    [product_count] => 
                    [children_data] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a try on the below one

`http://www.domain.com/rest/V1/categories/list?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=parent_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=3&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq`

`field` will be field name(**parent_id**)

`value` will be parent category id(**3**)

`conditionType` will be an operator (**eq**)

Response will be as follows:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "parent_id": 3,
      "name": "string",
      "is_active": true,
      "position": 3,
      "level": 3,
      "children": "",
      "created_at": "2020-04-23 11:08:14",
      "updated_at": "2020-04-23 11:08:14",
      "path": "1/2/3/4",
      "available_sort_by": [],
      "include_in_menu": true,
      "extension_attributes": {},
      "custom_attributes": [
        {
          "attribute_code": "is_anchor",
          "value": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "search_criteria": {
        "filter_groups": [
            {
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "field": "parent_id",
                        "value": "3",
                        "condition_type": "eq"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
  },
  "total_count": 1
}
```

Ref. https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#/catalogCategoryListV1/catalogCategoryListV1GetListGet